Prometheus Metrics with Labels Not Recording Values in Docker/Production Environment
If you have worked with Nextjs this is an easy question for you. Don't pay attention to the large amount of text.
I'm encountering an issue with Prometheus metrics in my Node.js application. Specifically, metrics with labelNames work correctly in the development environment (yarn dev) but fail to record values when running in Docker or on a staging server. The metric itself gets created and is visible at the /metrics endpoint, but no values are recorded for it.
Here's my code for initializing the metrics and recording durations:
const client = require("prom-client");

// Initialize metrics once
if (!global.isMetricsCollected) {
  console.log("[Metrics] Initializing metrics...");
  client.collectDefaultMetrics();
  global.isMetricsCollected = true;
}

// Define or retrieve httpRequestDuration with labels
let httpRequestDuration = client.register.getSingleMetric("http_request_duration_seconds");
if (!httpRequestDuration) {
  httpRequestDuration = new client.Histogram({
    name: "http_request_duration_seconds",
    help: "Duration of HTTP requests in seconds",
    labelNames: ['pathAddress', 'methodType', 'statusCode'],
  });
  client.register.registerMetric(httpRequestDuration);
}

// Function to track request duration
const trackMetrics = async ({ path, method, status, duration }) => {
  // Update duration metrics with labels
  if (duration) {
    httpRequestDuration.labels({ methodType: method, statusCode: status, pathAddress: path }).observe(duration);
  }
};

This works fine in development mode. However, when running the app in Docker or on staging, metrics are initialized, but the values don’t update.
Interestingly, the following simplified version (without labels) works both in development and in Docker/staging:
const client = require("prom-client");

// Initialize metrics
if (!global.isMetricsCollected) {
  console.log("[Metrics] Initializing metrics...");
  client.collectDefaultMetrics();
  global.isMetricsCollected = true;
}

// Define httpRequestDuration (optional, without labels)
let httpRequestDuration = client.register.getSingleMetric("http_request_duration_seconds");
if (!httpRequestDuration) {
  httpRequestDuration = new client.Histogram({
    name: "http_request_duration_seconds",
    help: "Duration of HTTP requests in seconds",
  });
  client.register.registerMetric(httpRequestDuration);
}

// Function to track request metrics
const trackMetrics = async ({ path, method, status, duration }) => {
  // Observe duration (if used)
  if (duration) {
    httpRequestDuration.observe(duration);
  }
};

I’m also using a middleware to calculate the duration and pass the data to the trackMetrics function:
import { trackMetrics } from "./../../../metrics-server";

export const handleMetrics = (path: string, method: string, status: number, startTime: number) => {
  const duration = (Date.now() - startTime) / 1000;

  const Path = path || "UNKNOWN";
  const Method = method || "UNKNOWN";
  const Status = status?.toString() || "500";

  console.log(
    `[MetricsMiddleware] Tracking metrics for method=${Method}, status=${Status}, path=${Path}, duration=${duration}s`
  );

  trackMetrics({ method: Method, status: Status, path: Path, duration });

  console.log("[MetricsMiddleware] Metrics successfully updated");
};

Questions: why might metrics with labelNames fails to record values in Docker or staging environments, while they work in development? Is there something I'm missing in how client.Histogram works with labels or Docker environments? How can I debug this further to determine the root cause?
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Verified that the labels (pathAddress, methodType, statusCode) are populated correctly.
Checked the /metrics endpoint to confirm that the metric itself is initialized.
Simplified the metric definition (removing labelNames), which works as expected even in Docker/staging.

